# É possível fazer um SPLIT direto em uma CONSULTA (SELECT) no SQL SERVER 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Tenho a seguinte tabela abaixo e preciso dividir a coluna "NomeCompleto" em colunas em um mesmo SELECT onde cada coluna deverá ser preenchida de acordo com seu nível.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ex: A coluna NomeCompleto deverá retornar em cada nova coluna o que for referente ao seu nível separado pelo ' \ ', porém o MAIOR e o MENOR nível não deve mudar de coluna conforme o que demonstro no excel abaixo. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?? Pesquisei bastante na internet, mas só achei funções que devem ser usadas em procedures.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O nível que varia de 0 a 3 (4 niveis) ...

4 NÍVEIS = NÍVEL 3 :

```
MAIOR   |    NIVEL 2   |  NIVEL 1  |   NIVEL 0
```

3 NÍVEIS = NIVEL 2

```
MAIOR   |   NULL    |  NIVEL1   |   NIVEL 0
```

2 NÍVEIS = NÍVEL 1

```
MAIOR  |   NULL   |  NULL    |  NIVEL 0
```

Comment: O que determina se um Nome é nível 0, 1 ou 2?

Comment: O nome sempre será o ultimo nível, neste ex, eu alterei na mão algumas colunas, considere a coluna nome igual a coluna "NomeNivel0". Desculpe pelo erro, estou corrigindo.

Comment: Perguntei errado também. O que determina se um **NomeCompleto** irá para a tabela **NomeNível0**, **NomeNível1** ou **NomeNível2**?

Comment: Vou colocar acima pq aqui ficou ruim de entender....

Comment: @JoséDiz esse artigo me ajudou muito. Não tenho palavras pra agradecer.. vlw mesmo.

Comment: @WallaceCarlos Se puder divulgar o artigo para os amigos já ajuda e muito na divulgação do [Porto SQL].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para separar colunas que possuem vários valores em uma mesma linha o usual é utilizar funções do tipo string split. Inclusive a partir da versão 2016 existe a função nativa STRING_SPLIT. Entretanto, quando é necessário que a separação dos valores seja retornada na mesma ordem, a função nativa STRING_SPLIT não garante.

No seu caso, versão 2012 do SQL Server, sugiro que utilize a função DelimitedSplit8K, de autoria de Jeff Moden. Informações adicionais sobre a função estão no artigo “[Separar conteúdo de texto multivalorado](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/01/27/separar-conteudo-de-texto-multivalorado_string-split/)”.

Eis solução que utiliza a função DelimitedSplit8K:

```
-- código #1
with Separado as (
SELECT id, max (nome) as nome, max (Nivel) as Nivel, 
    [I1]= max (case when SS.ItemNumber = 1 then SS.Item end),
    [I2]= max (case when SS.ItemNumber = 2 then SS.Item end),
    [I3]= max (case when SS.ItemNumber = 3 then SS.Item end),
    [I4]= max (case when SS.ItemNumber = 4 then SS.Item end)
  from tabela as T1
       cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (T1.NomeCompleto, '\') as SS
  --where ...
  group by id
)
SELECT id, nome, Nivel,
       I1 as NomeMaiorNivel,
       case when Nivel = 3 then I2 else '' end as NomeNivel2,
       case when Nivel >= 2 then I3 else '' end as NomeNivel1,
       case when Nivel >= 1 then I4 else '' end as NomeNivel0
  from Separado;
```

Não testei; pode conter erro(s).

---

Ainda no mesmo artigo há outras soluções. Eis a adaptação da solução proposta no item 3.4 para o seu caso:

```
-- código #2
with Separado as (
SELECT id, nome, Nivel,
       convert (XML,
                '<r><n>' + replace (NomeCompleto, '\', '</n><n>') 
                + '</n></r>'
               ) as Item
  from dbo.tabela
)
SELECT id, nome, Nivel,
       i.value('n[1]', 'varchar(20)') as NomeMaiorNivel,
       case when Nivel = 3 then i.value('n[2]', 'varchar(20)') else '' end as NomeNivel2,
       case when Nivel >= 2 then i.value('n[3]', 'varchar(20)') else '' end as NomeNivel1,
       case when Nivel >= 1 then i.value('n[4]', 'varchar(20)') else '' end as NomeNivel0
  from Separado as SX
       cross apply SX.Item.nodes('/r') Item(i);
```

Não testei; pode conter erro(s).